# how to stop plt.show() from making interface non-interactive

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

I'm writing an app that allows you to drag and drop datafiles unto a gui which then plots it. However using plt.show() causes the interface to become non-interactive, that means I need to first close the plot before dragging and dropping another file. I wanted to avoid doing this.

I've tried using plt.ion() but doing that causes the plot gui from updating when you resize it or try to manually close it.

Comment: Try `plt.show(block=false)`

Comment: @kindall I just tried that but again I have the same problem where the plot gui doesn't update when you try to resize it or close it.

Comment: If you do not use `plt.ion()` the GUI should stay responsive all the time. If it doesn't you would need to create a [mcve] of the issue and ask about it here.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest when you say here do you mean on this question or is there a special area for issues?

Comment: I mean that you should [edit] your question with a [mcve].